# Return an array from Model.findOne?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a query which retuns an array of documents as a promise (.exec).
Further I have a (promised) function which also returns an array. Both are combined in a Promise.all.

Now I want to move the `.find` to a `.findOne` to speed up the filter. But with `findOne` I would get no array back. So I decided to use `.find().limit(1)`

My question is if this is a valid approach, instead of the use of .findOne and if not: Is there a simple way to return the result of findOne as an array? Maybe with `.lean` ?

```
var query = Model.find({ $and: [ { _id: id }, 
                                 {  $or: [ { owner: userID }, 
                                           { isPublic: true } ]}
                            ]}).limit(1);

Promise.all([query.exec(), this._sources(user)]).then((doc: Array<any>) => {....}
```

Comment: Not sure this will help or not. Have you tried using [toArray()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findOne` returns an object, not an array. You can create an array with the result like this: `return [obj]`. I'm not sure but you can try this one

```
var queryResult = Model.findOne({ $and: [ { _id: id }, 
                  {  $or: [ { owner: userID },{ isPublic: true } ]}]})
                 .exec(function(err, data){
                        if(err) return [];                           
                        return [data];
                   });

Promise.all([queryResult, this._sources(user)]).then
```